# Can I detach a std::vector<char> from the data it contains?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I'm working with a function which yields some data as a `std::vector<char>` and another function (think of legacy APIs) which processes data and takes a `const char *, size_t len`. Is there any way to detach the data from the vector so that the vector can go out of scope before calling the processing function **without** copying the data contained in the vector (that's what I mean to imply with *detaching*).

Some code sketch to illustrate the scenario:

```
// Generates data
std::vector<char> generateSomeData();

// Legacy API function which consumes data
void processData( const char *buf, size_t len );

void f() {
  char *buf = 0;
  size_t len = 0;
  {
      std::vector<char> data = generateSomeData();
      buf = &data[0];
      len = data.size();
  }

  // How can I ensure that 'buf' points to valid data at this point, so that the following
  // line is okay, without copying the data?
  processData( buf, len );
}
```

Comment: Why not just keep the `data` vector in the function scope and call `processData( &data[0], data.size() )`??

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: In *this code sketch*, the scope of `processData()` is the direct ancestor of the scope of `data`. However, in real world code bases, there might dozen stack frames between the two scopes. Or imagine if `processData` would post the given buffer pointer and length to another thread and then return immediately - you have to ensure that the data remains valid until the consumer thread processed it. These are just two examples when you might want to decouple the lifetime of a container from the lifetime of the contained data.

Comment: Funny enough the answer you have accepted is exactly what I pointed in the previous comment just made more complex... instead of using a local vector and swapping with the global, just use the global... Now, that is different from what you are saying now. Transfer of ownership and lifetime management is better handled with (smart) pointers --just keep the container through a pointer and pass the ownership around...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
void f() { 
  char *buf = 0; 
  size_t len = 0; 
  std::vector<char> mybuffer; // exists if and only if there are buf and len exist
  { 
      std::vector<char> data = generateSomeData(); 
      mybuffer.swap(data);  // swap without copy
      buf = &mybuffer[0]; 
      len = mybuffer.size(); 
  } 

  // How can I ensure that 'buf' points to valid data at this point, so that the following 
  // line is okay, without copying the data? 
  processData( buf, len ); 
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks - I didn't realize there's a swap() member function on vectors.

Comment: @Frerich: STL containers generally feature a `swap` member, or a `swap` free function. It's not a requirement, it's just good design.

Comment: If you are going to provide a *global* (outer scope) vector, why not just generate the data into that container? `{ mybuffer = generateSomeData(); }`??

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: The code which calls `generateSomeData` doesn't have direct access to the `mybuffer` object. If it was that easy, I wouldn't have any need to detach the data in the first place. I wrote that in my response to your comment to my question already.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution has not even been presented yet:

```
void f() { 
   std::vector<char> data = generateSomeData(); 

  processData( &data[0], data.size() ); 
}
```

Comment: -1: This answers a question, but not the one I asked; I **intentionally** put a scope around the `data` vector so that it goes out of scope early to demonstrate my point.

Comment: @Frerich: but perhaps it answers the one you should have asked.

Comment: @Mike: Feel free to answer 'Beneath the big apple tree in the garden', just in case I meant to ask 'Where can I find some shadow during hot days?'. :-}

Comment: @Frerich: Taking that you have accepted a solution that *requires* adding a vector in the outer scope, this solution is just the simple elegant version of it... why do you want to create a second vector and swap if you can place the vector in the outer scope? My take is that you did not ask what you wanted to know, and a detail in the accepted answer helped you to a solution to the question you did not post.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: I asked how to detach a vector from the data it contains. I have no problem with creating a *second* vector (with a possibly longer lifetime!) for that. That's precisely the question which Alexey answered.

Comment: @Frerich: Sorry, but I still don't see your point. You have a vector that goes out of scope too early, so you transfer its contents to a longer living vector. What is then the problem with using the longer living vector to store the data in in the first place?

Comment: @Bart van Ingen Schenau: I cannot change the `generateSomeData` function, it's not under my control. It always generates a vector on the stack and passes it back to me. Now I need to pass the data in the vector to a different thread and that thread calls a legacy C API (also not under my control). So I need to ensure that the data in the vector lives long enough, until the other thread (and the legacy C function) finished their work. However, I want to avoid *copying* the data.

Comment: @Bart van Ingen Schenau: My solution is now to do a `new std::vector<char>` and then use the `swap()` function to swap the data from the vector returned by `generateSomeData` with my allocated vector. This ensures that the data lives until the `new`'ed vector is deleted. The other thread deletes the vector after calling the legacy API function.

Comment: @Frerich: The bit about communicating the data to another thread (instead of just to an outer scope) was missing from your question. My solution does indeed not work for the across-threads case.

Comment: @Bart van Ingen Schenau: Yes, true - I suppose I should've provided a bit more context to avoid this confusion (I had basically the same argument with "David Rodríguez - dribeas").

Answer (score 2):

I'm giving an answer to the original question below. However keep in mind that in most cases using `vector::data()` and reorganizing the code so that the mentioned vector doesn't go out of scope, using a different vector initialized with `vector(std::move(otherVector))` or swapping contents with another vector (`vector::swap(otherVector)`) is the better option as was pointed out in other answers.

Nevertheless there is a way to actually detach the data of a vector using a custom allocator. The following implements the allocator `Noalloc` that does absolutely nothing. It neither allocates/constructs stuff nor deallocates/destructs things. Also it doesn't contain any non-static or virtual member variables. So it shouldn't change the contents of an instance of `vector`. Inside `detachData` we cast an ordinary vector to a vector using the aforementioned allocator type by reinterpreting its type and move its content to a new vector with the same allocator. As the new vector runs out of scope it will try to destruct and deallocate its array contents. However as we've overridden that functionality within our custom allocator this does absolutely nothing. The function returns a pointer to the newly detached data of the original vector (which now holds a nullptr as data and zero elements).
Don't forget to destroy and deallocate the elements in the array manually afterwards!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <new>

// Our custom allocator
template <class T>
struct Noalloc {
    typedef T value_type;
    Noalloc() = default;
    template <class U> constexpr Noalloc(const Noalloc<U>&) noexcept {}
    T* allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t) noexcept {}
    template<class... Args> void construct(T* p, Args&&... args) {}
    void destroy(T* p) {}
};
template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(const Noalloc<T>&, const Noalloc<U>&) { return true; }
template <class T, class U>
bool operator!=(const Noalloc<T>&, const Noalloc<U>&) { return false; }

// detach the data from a vector and return its pointer
template<typename T>
    T* detachData(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    T* dataPtr = vec.data();
    // swap contents with a new vector
    // that uses "Noalloc" as allocator but is otherwise identical
    std::vector<T, Noalloc<T>> detachHelper
        (std::move(*reinterpret_cast<std::vector<T, Noalloc<T>>*>(&vec)));
    return dataPtr;
    // "detachHelper" runs out of scope here
    // But it will neither destruct nor deallocate
    // given data due to our custom allocator
}

// destroy and deallocate the data manually
template<typename T>
    void destroyData(T* data, size_t n, size_t capacity)
{
    // should be pretty self explanatory...
    std::allocator<T> alloc;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>::destroy(alloc, data+i);
    }
    std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>::deallocate(alloc, data, capacity);
}

int main()
{
    int* testData = nullptr;
    size_t size = 0;
    // For vectors data size and actually allocated size
    // may differ. So we need to keep track of both.
    // If you want to avoid this you may call "vector::shrink_to_fit()"
    // This should resize the vector to fit its data.
    // However the implementation is not required to fulfill this request.
    // So beware!
    size_t capacity = 0;
    {
        std::vector<int> test{1,2,3,4};
        // copy size and data pointer
        size = test.size();
        capacity = test.capacity();
        testData = detachData(test);
        // "test" runs out of scope here.
        // However after calling "detachData(test)"
        // it doesn't contain any data
    }
    // Print the contents of the array
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << testData[i] << std::endl;
    }
    // Don't forget to destroy the data yourself!
    // The original vector doesn't exist anymore
    destroyData(testData, size, capacity);
    std::cout << "data destroyed successfully" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The `*reinterpret_cast` causes undefined behaviour by strict aliasing violation

Answer (score -7):

I wouldn't recommend it, but:

```
char* ptr = NULL;
int len = -1;
{
    vector<char> vec;
    /* ... fill vec with data ... */
    vec.push_back(NULL); // dont forget to null terminate =)
    ptr = &vec.front();
    len = vec.size();
    // here goes...
    memset((void*)&vec, 0, sizeof(vec));
}
// vec is out of scoop, but you can still access it's old content via ptr.
char firstVal = ptr[0];
char lastVal = ptr[len-1];
delete [] ptr; // don't forget to free
```

Voila!

This code is actually pretty safe as vec's destructor will call `delete [] 0;`, which is a safe operation (unless you got some strange implementation of stl).

Comment: you have a strange definition of "safe".

Comment: I'm no language lawyer, but there's gotta be some undefined behavior there.

Comment: -1. All decent compilers should produce a warning on the `memset()` line.

Comment: @Dummy00001: Well,, they don't, it works, and its probably the only way to detach the array from the vector.

Comment: Oh god... kill it with a fire!

Comment: `delete [] ptr;` is certainly wrong, since by default `vector` uses `::operator new` and placement new (via `std::allocator`) to separately allocate memory and create objects. And the `memset` hack is undefined behavoiur, even if it does happen to have the right effect on your implementation.

Comment: @Dummy00001: Unfortunately will any complaint by a compiler be silenced by the cast to `void*`, but that does not remove the fact that the code is invoking UB.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: a char doesn't have a destructor, so it doesn't matter whether it uses placement new. I already pointed out I don't recommend it, and that it's dependent of the stl implementation.

Comment: The act of posting the code and calling it safe looks like a recommendation, even if you *say* it isn't.

Comment: @Viktor: placement new isn't the issue. Allocating with new and deallocating with delete[] is.  Even for POD, that is dangerous.

Comment: @Dennis: the vector internally allocates and deallocates with [] as it doesn't know the size of the array at compile time.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: Or you could see it as a solution which answers the question, but isn't recommended to do. Exactly as I say.

Comment: +1 for creative, practical thinking, and giving me a good laugh.

Comment: @Viktor: no, the vector internally allocates and deallocates with `::operator new()`, unless you give it a custom allocator that uses `new []`.

Comment: And the `memset` won't necessarily set the internal pointer(s) to null; null's representation isn't necessarily zero.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: "And the memset won't necessarily set the internal pointer(s) to null; null's representation isn't necessarily". Yes, there are a lot of reasons I said "pretty safe" instead of "safe", and started by saying I dont recommend it.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: "the vector internally allocates and deallocates with ::operator new()", ok, I thought the default allocater used new[] deep down somewhere.

Comment: -1 for continuing to argue that invalid code, exhibiting at least two instances of undefined behaviour, is "pretty safe".