# Move std::vector<T> to T*

Tags: c++, stl, vector, c++11, move-semantics

all
I've a legacy code which in draft does something like this:

```
// sadly I have to use this structure
struct LegacyStruct {
  int* values;
}
LegacyStruct* LgStr;
....
    std::vector<int> vec;
    // fill vector in some way here  

    size_t sz = vec.size();
    LgStr->values = new int[sz];
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), &LgStr->values[0]);
```

vec can be huge and I need to avoid copying it to int*.
Is there a way to do it?
I tried following:

```
// type of new operator explained in More Effective C++
LgStr->values = new (&vec[0])int[vec.size()];
```

Ok, `values` points to the beginning of vec inner array, **but it destroyed when vec is out of scope.** But I have to keep it..

```
&vec[0] = nullptr; // does not compile of course
```

So question is: is it possible to apply move semantics in this case?
Or maybe some other trick?

Comment: Here you go http://stackoverflow.com/q/3667580/57428

Comment: Couldn't you just work on LgStr->values instead of in the vector?

Comment: If what you really want is to "release" the internal dynamically-allocated array of `int` from the `vector`, and transfer ownership of that array to `LegacyStruct` to `delete[]` some time later, after the vector has been destroyed: no, you can't. The only good news is that copying to your array can't possibly be any slower than filling in the vector in the first place, so the missed opportunity for a speed-up is less than 50%.

Comment: @mfontanini Can't use ->values of course - otherwise I would not ask this)). It is very much simplified version of code - did not reveal all the operations with vec.
And I expected answer 'no' - asked just to make sure it is not really possible. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Just a quick thought (a.k.a. HACK): you could write your own allocator for `std::vector` (the second template argument) and implement `deallocate` as an empty function.

Comment: While C++11 has `std::move`, moving ints is no faster than copying them. Moving is intended for types like `std::string`.

Comment: @MSalters: I think the idea is to move the allocated array out of the vector and take manual ownership of it. Sadly, that's not possible.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Indeed. I'm just clarifying that this "move" isn't like a `std::move`. If you had a `std::vector<std::string>` and wanted to move that to a `std::string[]`, you could use `std::move` but that still would call O(N) move constructors.

Comment: @Andre that would result in leaked memory for everything the vector deallocates but which isn't the final array you take ownership over. But that might be on the right track.

Comment: @mfontanini I like your idea.  Maybe not for this specific case - but for most uses of vector the number of APIs used is probably quite small (push_back, size, empty, operator[]).  Writing a detachable vector for the APIs in use might be an easy solution.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that no, there isn't any way to transfer ownership of a `vector`'s buffer outside the `vector`.

I think your best option is to make sure that the `vector` just doesn't die by using a wrapper:

```
class LegacyStructWrapper : private boost::noncopyable  // Or declare private copy constructor/copy assignment or use `= delete` in C++11.
{
private:
    std::vector<int> vec_;
    LegacyStruct wrapped_;
}
```

Then anytime you need to use `values`, just assign it to `&vec_[0]`. This will stay constant if/until you add more items to the `vector` (so you *will* have to use care to make sure that vector resizes don't cause problems).

Comment: I'd suggest either implementing or deleting the copy constructor and copy-assignment operator, so you don't accidentally end up pointing to the wrong vector.

Answer (score 4):

Yup, you can do so - with a small trick:

```
struct LegacyStruct {
  std::vector<int> backingStore;
  int* values;
  LegacyStruct(std::vector<int>& aSource) {
    // Steal memory
    aSource.swap(backingStore);
    // Set pointer
    values = &backingStore[0];
  };
}
```

The `vector.swap` operation doesn't copy the ints.

Comment: sure this will work, but I have to add backingStore member to LegacyStruct (probably the way I'll do it in real code) which is undesirable because of other reason. Anyway thanks.

Comment: You can wrap LegacyStruct in another class and make it handle backingStore management. LegacyStruct would be unchanged then.